# What is the difference between combination reaction and addition reaction

Tags: redox

In my textbook,two definitions were given separately

> Combination: Two or more substances react to form one product.

> Addition: Something is added to a chemical substance without elemination.

What is the difference between this two reactions?

Comment: Looks like they mean the same thing, but combination is for inorganic compounds while addition reactions are for organic comcounds.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_reaction

But it looks like you can classify addition reactions, as a type of combination reaction.

Comment: CH SE site should not be your first choice to resolve textbook confusion, but rather the last one. If it is rather the last one, you should include compact summary of your prior looking for the answer.

Comment: "Combination" is an artificial term, a sort of baby talk, rarely used in that meaning outside a classroom. "Addition" is a real thing.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in terminology is probably due to the fact that an organic compound may have an atom or radical *added* in *different positions*.

For example, [propene reacts with $\ce{HI}$](https://www.nagwa.com/en/explainers/268186586415/) to form *both* 1-iodopropane and 2-iodopropane. Though Markovnikov’s rule implies the majority product is 2-iodopropane, some iodine is **added** at the terminal carbon, i.e., forming some 1-iodopropane.

We say the iodine is *added* at a location, not *combined* at a location.